# How to calculate available quantity from SQL joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am out of luck with a query with joins in a Postgres database.

I have to find out the available quantity with the given situation.

I have 4 tables (allocate, orders, orderitems, material):

- the `allocate` table has 3 columns `cntr_id` as contractor, `matid` as material, `qty_given`
- the `orderitems` table has `matid, qty_used, orderid`
- the `orders` table has `cntr_id, orderid`

My query is to find available stock with each contractor.

I thought it would be very easy to join tables to get the desired result but its not that easy.

I have tried many combinations of joins but to no gain and thus I need your help.

Let's see an example - my `allocate` table looks like this

```
select cntr_id, matid, qty_given 
from allocate
```

[result of above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOJXB.png)

This query returns a list of all the contractors, matid and qty_given.

The query here returns cntr_id, matid and qty_used:

```
select 
    o.cntr_id, i.matid, i.untsreq_perorder used
from
    orderitems i 
join 
    orders o on i.orderid = o.orderid
join 
    material m on m.matid = i.matid
group by 
    o.cntr_id, i.untsreq_perorder, i.matid
```

[result of above query with joins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it7IC.png)

This query returns a list of only those values which are used in order table which is fine. With this query I can find all the contractor and `qty_used` by them.

Now the main issue is how to use this second query to get available stock with contractors in the `allocated` table.

I have used several combinations of joins but without any success.

What I am trying to join is

```
select 
    a.cntr_id, a.matid, x.used
from
    allocate a
left join 
    (select o.cntr_id, i.matid, i.untsreq_perorder used
     from orderitems i 
     join orders o on i.orderid = o.orderid
     join material m on m.matid = i.matid
     group by o.cntr_id, i.untsreq_perorder, i.matid) x on a.cntr_id = x.cntr_id
group by 
    a.cntr_id, a.matid, x.used
```

The result is like this:

[result of above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGFw2.png)

Please help me find the approriate query to get available quantity with contractors.

I am extremely confused

Comment: Can you add a sample in dbfiddle? https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: i have added a sample for the above synario https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vsCsRLEDr6Vu582xwwv3f4/1

Comment: Your schema is really confusing and besides I think you didn't add all the columns.
I am getting error `Query Error: error: column i.untsreq_perorder does not exist`
Can you edit the question and show me a table where you put the exact result you want?

Comment: sorry, in the schema I put qty_used insted of untsreq_perorder. now i have correctd the issue

Comment: Can you show what result are you exactly looking for?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the support, by the way i have figured out the corret way to fetch the desired result.

```
select 
  a.matid, 
  a.cntr_id, 
  a.qty_given, 
  coalesce(sum(i.untsreq_perorder), 0) used, 
  coalesce((a.qty_given - i.untsreq_perorder),0) as available 
from 
  allocate a 
  left join orders o on o.cntr_id = a.cntr_id 
  left join material m on m.matid = a.matid 
  left join orderitems i on i.orderid = o.orderid 
  and i.matid = m.matid 
group by 
  a.matid, 
  a.cntr_id, 
  a.qty_given, 
  i.untsreq_perorder 
order by 
  a.cntr_id desc
```

the main logic which saved my life was the use of

```
left join orderitems i on i.orderid = o.orderid 
      and i.matid = m.matid
```

you can have a full view on

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vsCsRLEDr6Vu582xwwv3f4/1

thanks.